# mysql left join table 1 to table 2 by id where table 2 id newest date

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, table one

```
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| pixel    | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| metadata | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| data     | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| attended | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| alerted  | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date     | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table two

```
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lead_id          | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| project_id       | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id          | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type             | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status           | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| text             | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comm             | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sum              | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meeting_date     | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meeting_location | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date             | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to join table one to two on 1.id = 2.lead_id where 2.date is max
and then select it if 2.status equals x

I tried, about everything (accept the answer :D ), nothing got it.
Thank you.
 this question is different It has an AND cluse at the end

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/1503018). But you need additional left join.

Comment: Why do you want to join 1 to 2 if the only datas and conditions are on 2 (MAX(date) and status = "x") ?

Comment: do you need to display any data from T2?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT one.*, two.*
FROM one left join two on one.id=two.lead_id 
WHERE MAX(two.date) and two.status='x'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you only want the min/max of a single value as a condition, you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 0,1` to get a single row :)

```
SELECT *
FROM table_one
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM table_two
    WHERE status = XXXXXXXXX
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 0,1
) ON table_one.id = lead_id
```